# Xcode Autocomplete Member From Class Extension

Tags: xcode, swift, autocomplete, xcode6, xcode6.3

Autocomplete isn't working for me when accessing members from a class extension in Xcode (6.3.2).

I made a UIColor extension, and I am accessing them via `UIColor().sampleExtendedColorName()`, and it does not show up while I'm typing. Autocomplete works for everything other than this. Is there a setting I can change?

```
extension UIColor{
func sampleExtendedColorName() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:200/255, green:100/255, blue:120/255, alpha:1.0)
}
}
```

Update (new info):
So autocomplete is working if I access the UIColors from a ViewController that directly subclasses `UIViewController`, but if I subclass a custom `CustomViewController` that is a subclass of `UIViewController`, autocomplete doesn't show up for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure the extension is in scope? Your code works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, issue was on my ColorExtension.Swift file in my Xcode project. I needed to check all the Target Memberships.

Answer (score 1):

Checking all the Target Memberships is working fine. If you don't know where the Target Membership is,

- Go to your swift file (Eg: ViewController.swift)
- On the right side in the Utilities panel, Click file inspector
- You can see Target Membership there.
- Check all the fields.